# ajax call to webservice on external location

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, liferay

Hello im developing portlet for liferay and im trying to call webservice. I know i have to support CORS in jquery but even if defined i can only get respond from webservice with IE9 (?????). Chrome and mozilla just dont respond.

This is my code :

```
 jQuery.support.cors = true; 
 AUI().ready(function(){
 Liferay.on('senduid', function(data){
      var uid=data.data;
      var v="1.0";
      var q="dojo toolkit";
      $.ajax({ url: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=dojo%20toolkit', data: "&v="+v+"&q="+q, dataType: 'json',  success: function(data){
              alert('here...success');
      },
      // complete: function (data) {
      //     alert('here');
      // }
      });
 });
 });
```

As i said alert 'here succes' appears only in IE.

Can anybody help me how to do it?

PS : webservice should send something like this :

```
 "pages": [
            {
                "start": "0",
                "label": 1
            },
            {
                "start": "4",
                "label": 2
            }, ...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into a cross-domain issue. I'm guessing the security settings in your IE browser aren't disallowing cross-domain calls.  If you change the dataType value to 'jsonp' this will work.

I've got it working in a JSFiddle here: [JSFiddle Example - Working](http://jsfiddle.net/barryrowe/vHfjM/)

```
var uid = 'test';
var v = "1.0";
var q = "dojo toolkit";
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=dojo%20toolkit',
    data: {
        "v": v,
        "q": q
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        alert('here...success');
    }
});
```